# How to get the product type by the product SKU?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, search-criteria

I have some product SKUs in my custom module and I want to get just the simple products.
I don't want to load each product entity by SKU in a loop to get the product type to avoid performance issues.

How could I filter these products?

Comment: what is the response you are getting?

Comment: @aravind way to get the product id without loading the entire entity

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SearchCriteria** to get load the product JUST if this product exists with the type that you want.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
```

---

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
    ->addFilter('sku', $itemSku, 'eq')
    ->addFilter('type_id', Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, 'eq')
    ->create();
$productsItems  = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```